# Scope of further methods

Tags: java, scope

When discussing Java programming, I recently learned more about variable scoping and declaration and, more specifically, that **variables should be declared in the lowest scope possible.**  This got me thinking about the following example where we create a new object and send it to another function:

```
method  {
  while(statement) {
    Object newObject;
    //method code

    if(statement) {
      newObject = new object();
    } else {
      newObject = new object();
    }
    otherMethod(newObject)
  }
}
```

Compared to this example:

```
method  {
  while(statement) {
    Object newObject;
    //method code

    if(statement) {
      Object newObject;
      newObject = new object();
      otherMethod( newObject );
    } else {
      Object newObject;
      newObject = new object();
      otherMethod( newObject );
    }
  }
}
```

Which one is more correct?

Comment: In this case, I would say the first one because the if statement is just acting like a factory of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example uses less code and is usually preferred. Java will stop you from using a variable which may not have been initialized, so readability doesn't suffer much.

For even cleaner code you should employ the conditional operator:

```
otherMethod(condition? new ObjectA() : new ObjectB());
```

Comment: Thanks, I did't know you could do that!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the first method.  It is more flexable and easier to read.  The responsibility of the if statement is to create the object.  You can do it multiple ways and add additional logic to either the if or else branch and you know conceptually that once the if is done the Object is created and ready to go.  Since the method comes after the if, you know that it will always be called.  Since it shows the division of responsibilities better, that is the method I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the first one, as long as the things you do (e.g. calling other methods with the new instance) are always the same regardless of which way the if goes.

As a side note, if where you have "// method code" there is actually a lot of code, then I would recommend moving the variable declaration down to right before the if statement. That way you keep the declaration close to where it starts being used as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out that the first is clearer and probably generally preferred.  There is some room for opinion, but I expect that you'll find most will prefer that.  However, if you're attempting to keep things to the scope necessary, I'd suggest that you actually refactor the construction of the object out into a factory method, so that everything is even clearer.  Instead of:

```
public void frobSomeBars() {
  while ( condition1 ) {
    final Bar bar;
    if ( condition2 ) {
      bar = makeBarType1();
    } else {
      bar = makeBarType2();
    }
    frob( bar );
}
```

you could write a `Bar` factory method:

```
public Bar makeBar( final boolean condition ) {
  if ( condition ) {
    return makeBarType1();
  }
  else { 
    return makeBarType2();
  }
}
```

Note: I generally prefer to make methods with a tree of execution paths, with each leaf terminating in a return. Some will prefer a single return point, and would write the factory method as:

```
public Bar makeBar( final boolean condition ) { 
  final Bar bar;
  if ( condition ) {
    bar = makeBarType1();
  }
  else { 
    bar = makeBarType2();
  }
  return bar;
}
```

Then `frobSomeBars` is a bit simpler:

```
public void frobSomeBars() {
  while ( condition1 ) {
    final Bar bar = makeBar( condition2 );
    frob( bar );
}
```

or even:

```
public void frobSomeBars() {
  while ( condition1 ) {
    frob( makeBar( condition2 ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> variables should be declared in the lowest scope possible.

I believe what you are doing  comes under micro optimization.

> Which one is more correct?

I doesn't mean that write anything,`JVM` will maintain.In this case I suggest you to, do not go further and  stick to the first method, which is cleaner and more readable.

Comment: Re "I believe what you are doing comes under micro optimization":  It think this only applies if the OP is doing this _for the purpose of optimization_.   If this  is an optimization, then I agree it's sort of silly.  However, if it's to promote readability, then it's not bad.  (E.g., we use local variables in methods instead of introducing a bunch of fields in the class and using them instead, because it's much clearer.  (There would be other issues, too, of course, but this is just an example.))